# Creating database for an iOS application

Tags: ios, database, sqlite3-ruby

I'm coding an application for iOS. Which approach do you think is better: creating tables (create table foo) and everything at once, or only create the tables when it's necessary (only when the user goes to a certain view that uses that table) ? My prototype is creating tables only when it's needed. I have to decide if I'm doing it right in order to start developing my BETA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a good reason, create your tables and structure before hand and let the app update those table(s) as needed. Creating tables on the fly is overcomplicating the task.